# Gitlab without mail / let user sign up

Tags: gitlab

I'm having some trouble getting my mail setup to work with Gitlab 6 so I want the users to be able to sign up for an account and assign their own password instead of receiving the temporary password by mail.

Changes I've made:

/home/git/gitlab/config/gitlab.yml:

```
`signup_enabled: true`
```

But if I access Gitlab in the Browser it's still redirecting me to the "Sign in" page and I'm not able to "Sign up" or register a new account. Is there something I'm missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to restart the GitLab server after making that change.